# Formula Haversine - Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Necesito mostrar todas aquellas publicaciones, pero hay un filtro en particular. que  la distancia sea menor a 4km, según la coordenadas de esa publicación y mi actual ubicación.

como usuario, Tengo las coordenadas actuales.

Una publicación tiene sus coordenadas, de esta forma es como lo probé en php, para ver com funcionaba. pero ahora necesito hacerlo con una consulta real.

```html
public function ($lat1, $lon1,$lat2, $lat2) {

 $tierra = 6378;
 
    $dLat = deg2rad($lat2 - $lat1);
    $dLon = deg2rad($lat2 - $lon1);

    $a = sin($dLat/2) * sin($dLat/2) + cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * sin($dLon/2) * sin($dLon/2);


    $c = 2 * asin(sqrt($a));

    $d = $tierra * $c;
 
    
    return $d;
}
```

pero en eloquent ó usando algo más como lo haría¿?-

Estos son mis filtros que hago

```html
 $publicaciones = Publicacion::with(['user','categoria','archivos'])
                ->where('status','publico')
                ->whereHas('archivos')
                ->where('user_id','<>',auth()->user()->id)
             ->wherein('categoria_id',$listaCategorias)
                ->orwhereHas('places', function($q) use ($listaLugares) {
                    return $q->wherein('interesplaces.id',$listaLugares);
                 })
               
                ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
          ->paginate(10);
```

**En resumen : ¿Cómo pongo esa formula en mi consulta y que sea menor a 4km y de acuerdo a esas publicaciones aplicar los demás filtros.

Comment: Escribe la query en mysql o como quieras y ponla para ver que has intentado hacer.